# One to many map in Hibernate - error

Tags: java, hibernate, annotations, one-to-many

can anyone tell me where is the error in this example

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ITEM")
public class Item  implements Serializable
{

@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name = "ID")
private Long id;

@Column(name = "NAME")
private String name;

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "ID_ITEM",referencedColumnName="ID")
private List<ItemDetail> itemDetails;
```

second class

```
 @Entity
    @Table(name = "ITEM_DETAIL")
    public class ItemDetail  implements Serializable
    {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "NAME")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "ID_ITEM")
    private Long itemId;
```

and the db

```
COMMIT;

CREATE TABLE item(
id serial PRIMARY KEY,
name VARCHAR(16)
);
CREATE TABLE item_detail(
ID serial PRIMARY KEY,
NAME VARCHAR(16),
ID_ITEM serial REFERENCES item (id)
);

COMMIT;
```

The error i got is

```
Hibernate: select nextval ('hibernate_sequence')
Hibernate: select nextval ('hibernate_sequence')
Hibernate: select nextval ('hibernate_sequence')
Hibernate: insert into ITEM (NAME, ID) values (?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into ITEM_DETAIL (ITEM_ID, NAME, ID) values (?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into ITEM_DETAIL (ITEM_ID, NAME, ID) values (?, ?, ?)
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: Could not execute JDBC batch update
    at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:90)
    at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.executeBatch(AbstractBatcher.java:275)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:266)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:167)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:321)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:50)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1027)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:365)
    at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.commit(JDBCTransaction.java:137)
    at com.mkyong.common.App.main(App.java:51)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:115)
Caused by: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Batch entry 0 insert into ITEM_DETAIL (ITEM_ID, NAME, ID) values (NULL, id1, 161) was aborted.  Call getNextException to see the cause.
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement$BatchResultHandler.handleError(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:2530)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1317)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:350)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeBatch(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:2592)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.BatchingBatcher.doExecuteBatch(BatchingBatcher.java:70)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.executeBatch(AbstractBatcher.java:268)
    ... 13 more

Process finished with exit code 1
```

It's obviously that item_id is null but why??

Thanks
Regards

Comment: Can you post the definition of `hibernate_sequence` in the database?

Comment: Its created implicitly during execution the query creating the tables.

Comment: look at this line 
Caused by: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Batch entry 0 insert into ITEM_DETAIL (ITEM_ID, NAME, ID) values (NULL, id1, 161) was aborted.  Call getNextException to see the cause.

Answer (score 1):

@backebg: can you check your db script and let us know that you executed exactly same in Database. If yes then either correct your entities to use "ID_ITEM" or item_detail table to use 'ITEM_ID' instead 'ID_ITEM'. thanks

Comment: It was incorrect annotation - but after even i changed the entity to ID_ITEM the same problem persist :( Thanks

Comment: In Item entity it is still ITEM_ID. lets make try to change it again and check the exception as well, is it same as before? thanks.

Comment: Ops.Yes the same error persist :( and the exception is that one. Thanks Asad.

Answer (score 1):

Having ITEM_ID mapped as a column in `ItemDetail` is a bit odd, and mapping it that way might might be the source of the problem.  Nothing is telling the `ItemDetail` class that that field should be populated with a proper id for the parent `Item`, including that it shouldn't be null.

If the detail doesn't need to know about the parent, you might be able to just omit that field in the `ItemDetail` java code altogether.  The field in the table should be populated as a consequence of the relation.

It's more common to map this sort of thing as a  bidirectional association, so that you have a `@OneToMany` relation of `Item` to `ItemDetail` and a `@ManyToOne` relation of `ItemDetail` to `Item`, and the relations can be navigated in Java.  If the `ItemDetail` does need to know about the parent item,  you should do it this way.

This is described somewhere in the [Hibernate Annotations Reference section on mapping associations](http://docs.jboss.org/ejb3/app-server/HibernateAnnotations/reference/en/html_single/index.html#entity-mapping-association).

Comment: Thanks for the post Don. I will check it out. :)

Answer (score 1):

Use `nullable = false` to tell Hibernate that the join column cannot be null:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ITEM")
public class Item  implements Serializable {

    // ...

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "ID_ITEM", referencedColumnName = "ID", nullable = false)
    private List<ItemDetail> itemDetails;

    // ...
}
```

and remove the `itemId` property from `ItemDetail` as it is already mapped by the `@JoinColumn` annotation. If you need the `itemId`, then use a bi-directional relationship (hold a reference to the entire `Item` object, not just the ID).